# Label Markers On ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I would like to make a scatter plot where each element corresponds to a certain energy.  Each plot marker should have its corresponding element next to it.  IE.  The data point at -1.16187 should have "Sc" next to it.  How can this be done?

```
data = {-1.16187, -1.48643, -3.31205, -0.541609, -4.18021, -4.79914,
   -4.3378, -3.10561, -0.968065, -1.1105, -8.40646, 0, -1.61386,
   -1.12215, -1.55604, -1.40126, -1.23439, -1.01761, -1.31265, -1.63032,
   -1.4456, -0.944587, -1.45256, -1.49496, -1.38007, -1.12108, -1.04517};

elements = {"Sc", "Ti", "V", "Cr", "Mn", "Fe", "Co", "Ni", "Cu", "Zn", "Y",
   "Zr", "Nb", "Mo", "Tc", "Ru", "Rh", "Pd", "Ag", "Hf", "Ta", "W",
   "Re", "Os", "Ir", "Pt", "Au"};

p1 = ListPlot[{#} &@data, FillingStyle -> Thick,
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}]
```

Comment: `ListPlot[{#} &@data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, 
 Epilog -> (Text[First@#, Rest@## + {0, .25}] & /@ (Transpose[{#, Range@Length@#, data}] &@elements))]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dataPlot = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize -> Large, AxesOrigin -> {0, -9}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-9, 1}}];
labels = MapThread[Text[#1, {#2, #3 + 0.3}] &, {elements, Range[Length@data], data}];
Show[dataPlot, Graphics[labels]]
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 16):

Here is an illustration using [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) that shows automatic placement:

```
ListPlot[
  MapThread[Labeled, {data, elements}],
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.015]
]
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like `Labeled` in the first example positions the labels to avoid collisions. I didn't know it did that.

Comment: @Simon I think that was one of the new-in-v10 features.  I'll see if I can find a reference.

Comment: @kguler I already voted for your pretty answer.  I merely wanted to give a simpler example.  I feel our present posts are complementary, but if you wish to include your original code (which I didn't see) in your present post I can delete this one.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, i updated to include the original answer. By the way, I am glad you posted this answer, because, otherwise, i don't think i would ever notice the collision avoidance Simon noticed.

Comment: @kguler Okay, I kept only that part of my answer.

Comment: Adding Joined->True and PlotMarkers->Automatic will still try to give you the best placements.

Answer (score 14):

With some decoration :

```
With[{coord = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, data]}, 
   Graphics[{MapThread[Style[Text[#1, #2 + If[OddQ[#2[[1]]], {0, 2}, {0, -2}]],
       Black, 18, Italic] &, {elements, coord}], PointSize[Large], Gray, 
         Line[{#, # + If[OddQ[#[[1]]], {0, 1.4}, {0, -1.4}]}] & /@ coord, 
           Blue, Point@coord}, Axes -> {None, True}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -9}, 
             ImageSize -> 500]]
```

[image]

Comment: qwrety, +1, but if Cr value were a little higher (eg maybe with different data), it would be next to Mn and read CrMn.

Answer (score 5):

```
ListPlot[List /@ (Labeled[#, Style[#2, 12, "Panel"], Top] & @@@ 
    Transpose[{Transpose[{Range@Length@data, data}], elements}]),
 Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Automatic,
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, "ColorList"], 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[{Opacity[1.], Thickness[.02], PointSize[.025]}],
 ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> 25, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

```
ListPlot[Thread@Labeled[data, elements, Right], Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> Thick, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}]
```

Answer (score 2):

May I cheat by deleting "ZR" and its associated `0` value and plotting with positive Y-ticks?

```
BarChart[-data,
 BarOrigin -> Top,
 BarSpacing -> 0.5,
 ChartElementFunction -> "GradientScaleRectangle",
 ChartLabels -> Placed[elements, Above],
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 ImageSize -> 500,
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
 PlotRangePadding -> {{None, 0.5}, {None, 0.3}},
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]