# Simple ListPlot with different colors and labels

Tags: plotting, color, labeling

I want to plot a list of points where every point has a different colour. Is it also possible to label these points according to a list of sample names I have in Excel? Please help.

Comment: Giving a different color to each point is not that hard, you can use `Style`, look at the help page for `ListPlot` and you find the example `ListPlot[Table[
  Style[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, Hue[t/(2 Pi)]], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do find it difficult to apply it to my case though. I simply have an imported list of points from Excel that I would like to plot in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListPlot` accepts a list of list of points, assigning new colours to each of the sublists.

```
points = Table[{{RandomReal[{1, 10}], RandomReal[{1, 10}]}}, {i, 1, 10}]

(* {{{1.54315, 3.96704}}, {{6.2341, 6.44874}}, {{1.88163, 
5.46795}}, {{2.37001, 7.649}}, {{6.74071, 3.67992}}, {{9.87758, 
4.82062}}, {{9.71256, 2.90955}}, {{2.53583, 6.80984}}, {{9.04613, 
1.49516}}, {{8.10797, 4.08785}}} *)

labels = Table["Dot " <> ToString[i], {i, 1, 10}]

ListPlot[points, PlotLegends -> labels]
```

gives

[image: ListPlot example with multiple colours]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I formulated my imported dataset into the Table format you have here and then the rest worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Any idea if I could have the labels next to each data point? By using PlotMarkers and Table command perhaps?

Comment: Have a look here:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63570/19176

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a ton! :)