# How do I label points when using Graphics?

Tags: graphics, labeling

Let say I want to draw a point and label it. The command I use to draw points is

```
Graphics[{Point[{0,0}], Point[{1,1}]}]
```

This draws the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. How can I label them in the resulting graphics as $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$?

Comment: Look up `Text[]`.

Comment: Also see [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html), and perhaps [(45496)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45496/121)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Labeling points of intersection between plots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32081/labeling-points-of-intersection-between-plots)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a somewhat ridiculous way to achieve that:

```
ListPlot[
 {Labeled[{0, 0}, "The first point"], Labeled[{1, 1}, "The second one", Left]},
 Axes -> False
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: this has the added advantage of using the built-in algorithms for label placement. +1

Comment: @rcollyer that's what I was getting at with my link to [(45496)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45496/121) above.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard expecting me to follow every link? Sheesh, you would think I spent all my time surfing the net. :)

Comment: @rcollyer lol - no :-)

Comment: The code didn't work in Mma10.0.2

Comment: @Harry strange. I believe I was using v.10 when I wrote this answer, so it should work. What exactly didn't work when you tried? Did you get an error message? What was the output?

Comment: @MarcoB When I try the code above in y Mma10.0.2 on my WIN7, It throw out :"Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {1, 2} -> {"The first point"} cannot be combined" and " MapThread::mptc: "Incompatible dimensions of objects at positions {2, 2} and {2, 3} of MapThread[Text[#1, Offset[-{2, 1} #3, #2], #3] &, {{"The first point"}, {{0., 0.}}, {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}}]; dimensions are 1 and 2.""

Comment: @MarcoB the output was two blue points lay as in your answer while only the second point get labeled. The whole output was covered by pink rectangle which represents error :"MapThread is not a Graphics primitive or directive "

Comment: `ListPlot[{Labeled[{0, 0}, "The first point"], Labeled[{1, 1}, "The second one"]}]` work well without "Left" in Mma10.0.2 on my WIN7. And your answer under https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45496/label-markers-on-listplot works well